# How to develop an android app using xamarin based on existing SharePoint server?

Tags: android, sharepoint, xamarin, mobile-application

I am currently assigned for a task that requires me to build a mobile app/client, based on existing SharePoint server. All I have so far is the idea to build the app using Xamarin on Visual Studio and later I might connect it with SharePoint.

Can anybody explain to me the steps to do so?

Or if anybody have a better idea on developing SharePoint mobile app not using xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dev your mobile App, you need to use **REST API** of SharePoint or you can use the CSOM (Client SharePoint Object Model).

have a look at this link witch explain how to do that with rest api : [Build mobile apps for other platforms using SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj870858.aspx)

Comment: I'll do my best to try what you suggested @Nico, thankyou

Answer (score -2):

From the little I understand regarding Sharepoint, you will need the app you build to connect to the SQL Server in order to use the data thats on the sharepoint server?

Comment: So in that case i should build the app first and then connect it with SharePoint?

Comment: Well how else would you do it? can't connect the app you haven't created yet to the sharepoint server?

Comment: You got a point.. say i have the app built, any idea how to integrate them?

Comment: Do a bit of searching on SO, i do know you will need a JDBC driver to be able to connect to the SQL database, i myself have not done something like this.

Comment: Ok appreciate the help

Comment: If I understand your discussion, you will develop an mobile app witch is connected to SharePoint by using the Server SQL of SharePoint. WARNING ! if it's this. It's forbiden to use SharePoitn Database directly from SQL (you will lost the Microsoft Support)